# With C# under what circumstances do I need to supply a CultureInfo IFormatProvider when using ToString() on a String or Char?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring, culture

With C# under what circumstances do I need to supply a `CultureInfo` `IFormatProvider` when using `ToString()` on a `String` or `Char`?

I get it with number or date conversion, e.g.

```
(-10000.4).ToString(provider: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"));
(-10000.4).ToString(provider: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

DateTime.Now.ToString(provider: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"));
DateTime.Now.ToString(provider: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

giving:

```
-10000,4
-10000.4
01/05/2018 22:49:09
5/1/2018 10:49:09 PM
```

but what about the following:

```
"Some string".ToString(provider: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"));
"Some string".ToString(provider: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

What strings could I possibly use that would be affected by culture?

Same for `char`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under no circumstance, since it does not do anything. As the [MSDN documentatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dxe1x2(v=vs.110).aspx)n for `String.ToString(IFormatProvider provider)` states:

> `provider` is reserved, and does not currently participate in this
>   operation.
>
> Because this method simply returns the current string unchanged, there
>   is no need to call it directly.

The same applies to `Char.ToString(IFormatProvider provider)`.

---

The reason why `String` and `Char` have this apparently useless method is 
that it is needed to implement the `IConvertible` interface, that e.g. allows conversion from `string` to `int`, `int` to `string` etc.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, a case of RTFM then :-) Although one then wonders why it's implemented at all.